# php not displaying all the output of console

Tags: php, apache, console-application

I am calling an exe from php. The exe takes about 12-15 sec to execute.I am displaying its output to check whether it is working or not. It seems that the output is only the first line.I had done exactly the same thing for another exe which is working fine. I don't know where the problem is.The exe when run from console displays all the output.But there is a delay to displaying the output after the first line.Can this cause the termination. The output which I am getting in console is

```
All warnings have the state 'off'.
%There is around 5 sec delay after this statement

Input Image Coarse labels
brown
red
white
Input Image Fine labels
     3

medium carmine
white
rose taupe
handbags\Satchel\2249a1363696156.jpg
brown
red
gray
     3

medium carmine
rose taupe
seashell
handbags\Hobos\5e7d81363672105.jpg
brown
red
white
     3

medium carmine
white
auburn
handbags\Satchel\598551363671893.jpg
brown
red
pink
     3

medium carmine
auburn
linen
handbags\Shoulder Bags\199291363674661.jpg
brown
red
black
     3

medium carmine
caput mortuum
pale chestnut
handbags\Shoulder Bags\d0f571363669974.jpg
brown
red
white
     3

medium carmine
white
rose taupe
handbags\Wallets\621de1363696385.jpg
brown
red
pink
     3

medium carmine
chestnut
khaki
handbags\Cross Body\b06731363673898.jpg
brown
gray
white
     3

rose taupe
misty rose
medium carmine
handbags\Backpacks\7beee1363672636.jpg
brown
red
pink
     3

medium carmine
caput mortuum
copper rose
handbags\Clutches\f7b7d1363673095.jpg
brown
red
pink
     3

medium carmine
caput mortuum
puce
handbags\Cross Body\e6e551363672712.jpg
brown
red
pink
     3

medium carmine
burnt umber
copper rose
Elapsed time is 6.855536 seconds.
```

The output that I am getting in php is:

```
Array ( [0] => Warning: No display specified. You will not be able to display graphics on the screen. [1] => All warnings have the state 'off'. )
```

Ignore the warnings.I think the exe is running otherwise the 'All warnings have that state off' would not be shown. Any solutions to this problem??? I am using Linux OS I used make file to compile the C++ exe.

My code in php is:

```
$addr="/home/fashion/fashion_shoe/shoesfinal $image $cwt $fwt $swt $twt";
exec($addr,$data);
print_r($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$data = shell_exec($addr);
```